# $.ajax() not firing req to server side in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have the following Javascript code snippet. The same code works in Chrome but doesn't in Firefox

```
var ajaxSettings = {
            type:"POST",
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("myheader", "funny");
            },
            processData: false            
        };

$.ajax("template", ajaxSettings)
    .done(function() { log("template success"); })
    .fail(function() { log("template error"); })
    .always(function() { log("template complete"); });
```

The above settings work in Chrome but not in Firefox. Am I missing something? It works well in IE9 too.

I had a debugger breakpoint in the server code. The request was not fired to server in case of Firefox. And in the firebug 'Net' panel, there was no entry for request being made.

Comment: Where is the url of the request?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome and IE have different Cross-Domain policies, the URL is kind of important.

Comment: @LightStyle URL is there in the second statement "template" . Should I provide the complete URL of the same to make it work?

Comment: The best way, IMHO, is to use `url: "template.php(?)"` in `ajaxSettings` and pass only the object to `$.ajax()`

Comment: In firefox did you not get anything in the console? If so, what does log() look like ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov I am not trying anything complex. I am just trying to create a simple servlet class. So my question is 'Is there a way can we find that something is supported or not supported from javascript code itself?'

Comment: You should also pass `success: function(){...}` and `error: function() {...}` in `ajaxSettings`, but it is only a type of writing code(which I prefer). Try passing them this way and see if it works.

Comment: @adeneo log() just a function which does console.log() For firefox, there was nothing in the log i.e. neither error nor the strings I have logged.

Comment: The code in the question should work with all major browsers if you're using a newer version of jQuery.

Comment: It works just fine in firefox for me, did you use the "all" tab, as the logged messages don't show in the "error" tab in firebug ?

Comment: Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h3Q8/4/) in firefox, and see if the messages show ?

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had a code which did initial ajax setup. This was commented and the code worked. The problematic code is provided below `$.ajaxSetup({
     url: "/hello/",
     global: false,    type: "POST"  
  });` Please let me know if this code was really causing the problem

Comment: @adeneo The fiddle works in firefox.. BTW how do you quickly test ajax codes without server side support?

Comment: By using the “server side support” jsfiddle already provides – see item titled "Ajax Requests" on the left.

Comment: The code in the comment would use `/hello/` as an URL, so that probably does'nt work, but should still have triggered the `fail()` and `always()` callbacks? To test an ajax call you can use jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try this exapmle:

```
    var ajaxSettings = {
            url:"http://mydoamin.com/mypage.cfc",
            type:"POST",
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("myheader", "funny");
            },
            processData: false            
        };

$.ajax("template", ajaxSettings)
    .done(function() { log("template success"); })
    .fail(function() { log("template error"); })
    .always(function() { log("template complete"); });
```